# Get Combobox Value in VS

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am making a simple pricing calculator by using a Combobox and Label Text. 
My Combobox has 2 items: Weekend (30.000) and Weekday (20.000). While the multiplier is quantity.

So if I choose "Weekend (30.000)" in the combobox and input "2" to qty, the result would be 30.000 * 2 = 60.000.

I tried this code but could not work.

I wonder how do I get the value of the strings from "Weekend (30.000)" to 30000?

```
Private Sub txtQty_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtQty.TextChanged
        Try
            lblFinal.Text = cboPrice.SelectedItem * txtQty.Text 
           Catch ex As Exception    
        End Try
End Sub



Private Sub cboPrice_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboPrice.SelectedIndexChanged
    Try
        If cboPrice.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            cboPrice.SelectedItem = "30000"
        ElseIf cboPrice.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            cboPrice.SelectedText = "40000"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict.  `lblFinal.Text = cboPrice.SelectedItem * txtQty.Text ` is multiplying Object times String and assigning the Double result to a string property

Answer (score 0):

I tried again using this code and it worked. . .

```
Dim price as integer

Private Sub txtQty_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtQty.TextChanged

        Try

            lblFinal.Text = Price * CInt(txtQty.Text)

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub



    Private Sub cboPrice_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboPrice.SelectedIndexChanged

        Try
            If cboPrice.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
                Price = 30000
            Else
                Price = 40000
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```